# Needing to separate two meshes while keeping some parts stuck together

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGPvxIrobFE&t=2335s) of making a car. If you scroll up to 38:30 you can see he separate the two meshes, and a bit later want us to connect some parts of the mesh together while keeping them two different meshes. I tried using the move, fill and merge tools, but they don't seem to give the same results. It would be easier to work if the two meshes are one object, but I will need them to be separate for later steps.
[Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApK6_VE0-zvYmCRwMaB6CTI7R8CF?e=eTFVgu)
In short, how can I make it look like this [image]

When it's like this
[image]

Comment: I don't know what he does in the video but you can't connect meshes that are in separate objects if this is your question

Comment: Should I edit it as one object and do some workaround in the future steps where I need them to be separate?

Comment: it looks like he wants to use a modifier on the separate object, that's probably why he separates this part, when he will have finished he will probably join the parts again

Comment: I will try to do it without separating the object. Thank you for helping